# how to loop a set of links given in an array using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

**i don't know this for loop or is there some other way out. I am new to selenium**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
a=["http://www.googgle.com","http://www.youtube.com","http://www.facebook.com"]
for i in a:
    driver.get(a[i])
```

Comment: `driver.get(i)`

Comment: You are opening three sites. What's the point?

Comment: its relating to a fun project

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
a=["http://www.googgle.com","http://www.youtube.com","http://www.facebook.com"]
for i in a:
    driver.get(a)
```

There is no point in using indexing there.